# How to define imageaffine background color on php?

Tags: php, gd

I'm applying an affine transformation (scale and rotation) on an image using imageaffine:

```
$scale = 0.5;
$rot = pi()/4;
$a = $scale * cos($rot);
$b = $scale * sin($rot);

// Affine matrix is defined as [ a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2 ];
$affinematrix = [$a ,$b, -$b, $a, 0, 0];
$output = imageaffine($input, $affinematrix);
```

The function adds a white background because of the rotation. Is there any way to change this white background to black?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used `imagescale` and `imagerotate` instead.  The `imagerotate` function allowed to change my background color.

```
$background_color = 0; // Black

// Scaling
$tmp = imagescale($input, $scale * $width, $scale * $height);

// Rotation
$output = imagerotate($tmp, rad2deg($rot), $background_color);
```